# Saving Excel file takes much time

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to open an Excel file, to write something in and then save it. My problem is that the saving part (workbook.write) takes a lot of time. 
that's my code:

```
 FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(f2);
 XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
 XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Tabelle1");
 //Some clonesheet, createrows, createcells, setting style & value
 //about 2 sheets ,10 rows * 10 cells
 workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(path)); //takes about 2 minutes
 workbook.close();
```

I am executing the code on a production machine where i can't do any modification on the JVM. I know that the heap memory is quite small. (i can't open excel files bigged than 2mb) I don't know if this is in relation to my problem.

thank you

Comment: Looks like your connection to the network storage is kinda slow

Answer (score 0):

Use buffer instead of direct field path, something like:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int n = 0;
while (-1 != (n = is.read(buffer))) {
   fos.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
```

or follow by [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.html#write-java.io.OutputStream-):

> If stream is a FileOutputStream on a networked drive or has a high
>   cost/latency associated with each written byte, consider wrapping the
>   OutputStream in a **BufferedOutputStream** to improve write performance.

Comment: i am in fact working on a network storage, i don't have any access on local storage. I tried to wrap fileOutputStream into a BufferedOutputStreamm. But it takes much time too